# How can I change the pathname of a image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
searchURL: function() {
    function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }
    var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
        emailUrl = /\/img\//,
        newstr = '',
        doc = document,
        container,
        container_id,
        container_links,
        container_images,
        documentTableWrapper,
        docBodyFirstChild,
        nodeToTargetToInsertLP;

    if (!doc.getElementById('container')) {
        container = doc.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
        container.className = 'container-avon-representative-news';
        container_links = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
        container_id = doc.getElementById('container');
        docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
        nodeToTargetToInsertLP = doc.getElementsByClassName('flexTile')[4];


        if (nodeToTargetToInsertLP) {
            documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByClassName('marginfix')[0];
            container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
            insertAfter(container, nodeToTargetToInsertLP);
        } else {
            documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
            container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
            doc.body.insertBefore(container, docBodyFirstChild);
        }


    } else {
        container_links = doc.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');
    }
    container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
       if (arguments[0] == "smo" || arguments[1] == "smodev") { 
          container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/dir_a/');
      } else {
          container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/dir_b/');

      }
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) { 
        url = getURL(arguments[i]); 
        for (var j = 0, jlen = container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) { 
            link = container_links[j];
            if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) { 
                parser = document.createElement('a'); 
                parser.href = link.href;

                link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                newPathName = parser.pathname;


                if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) { 
                    newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
                    newstr = newPathName;

                } else {
                    newstr = newPathName;
                }
                link.href = newstr;
            } else {
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

            }
        }
    }
},
```

I have a loop which is going through the images which are children of a div:

```
var container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img'),
            emailUrl = /\/img\//;
  for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
      if (arguments[0] == "smo" || arguments[1] == "smodev") { 
          container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/dir_a/');
      } else {
          container_images[i].src = container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/dir_b/');

      }
  }
```

Strangely, this is working in one instance (another area of the server), but in another instance it's adding other pathnames/directories which I didn't even indicate?!

I figured `replace` is explicit enough:

```
xxx.src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/dir_a/');
```

If this `image` tag has its source attribute set to `/\/img\//` replace it with `/images/dir_a/`

Does anyone know a method which is more explicit and won't add directories which I didn't assign?

And could anyone explain how this is happening with the `replace` method?

**UPDATE**
To give some background the environment where I am not having any problems is as follows: My company uses a CMS to serve these pages. The file extension is called `.page`; I have never heard of that extension outside the use of the CMS so I supposed it's proprietary to the CMS.

Anyway, in the CMS you can also server `html` files like you would from any other server. But in this instance, when I check the source in dev tools, it seems to add `<img src="http://xxx.xxx.com/REPSuite/static/html/inews_archives/static/images/dir_b/xxx.png">` instead of `<img src="http://xxx.xxx.com/REPSuite/static/images/dir_b/xxx.png">`

Comment: What "directories you didn't assign"? Can we have an example of expected vs. actual output?

Comment: console.log the src before you try to replace...see what it is saying

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @dMd I am updating the question...

Comment: what `arguments` is ? Are you inside a function?

Comment: @Hitmands It is. That's just to check which environment the script is running. There is yet another environment where I don't need to have every part of the greater function to run.

Comment: @Hitmands I added the whole function in a snippet. It is actually a method of a object.

Comment: are the image src inside the html relative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be so simple (of course after the fact). Anyway—because I was getting that funky path ***only*** in the other environment where the page was getting served, I simply made a conditional which checked for ***that*** funky path.

So instead of checking one regex I checked for two.

```
var emailUrl = /img\//gi,
    tsUrl = /\/REPSuite\/static\/html\/inews_archives\/img\//gi;


for (var i = 0; i < avon_rep_container_images.length; i++) {
     if (arguments[0] == "smo" || arguments[1] == "smodev") { // Checks what environment the page will be used in so we can change the src attribute of all the images in the document to the appropriate path
         avon_rep_container_images[i].src = avon_rep_container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/images/avon_manager_news/');
    } else if(!nodeToTargetToInsertLP) {
         avon_rep_container_images[i].src = avon_rep_container_images[i].src.replace(tsUrl, '/REPSuite/static/images/rep_news/');
    } else {
        avon_rep_container_images[i].src = avon_rep_container_images[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/static/images/rep_news/');
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped out, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using `.src` and you want to be using `.getAttribute('src')` and `.setAttribute('src', 'your new src')`.

> **HTMLImageElement.src**
>
> Is a DOMString that reflects the src HTML
>   attribute, containing the full URL of the image including base URI.

so when you call `.src` it gives you the full absolute current uri. You just want to get/set the src attribute. [working example jsbin](http://jsbin.com/segisigaba/edit?html,js,console)